# How to separate unit and integration/long running tests on Jest?

Tags: jestjs

Currently, I have two folders: `__tests__` for unit (fast) tests and `__integration__` for slow tests.

Then, in `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:integration": "jest -c '{}'",
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "__integration__"]
  }
}
```

So, when I want to do TDD, I'm running just `npm test` and when I want to test the entire project, `npm run test:integration`.

As Jest is offered as a "no configuration" test framework, I was thinking if there's a better (or proper) way to configure this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

Quoting from this [post](https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/organizing-tests-in-jest-17fc431ff850).

You can try name files like:

`index.unit.test.js` and `api.int.test.js`

> And with Jest’s pattern matching feature, it makes it simple to run
>   them separately as well. For unit testing run `jest unit` and for
>   integration testing run `jest int`.

File structure/location you can define based on your preferences as the pattern matching based on the file name is how jest knows what to run.

Also see [jest cli documentation about npm scripts](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#using-with-npm-scripts):

> If you run Jest via `npm test`, you can still use the command line
>   arguments by inserting a `--` between `npm test` and the Jest arguments

Comment: additionally: if you have unit tests named `something.test.js` and integration tests named `somethingElse.int.test.js` you can exclude integration tests in your unit test run with a negative look-behind regex: `jest ^((?!\.int).)*$`

Comment: Nice @MarkoBjelac, so putting it inside the package.json it would be written as:
```"test:unit": "jest \"^((?!\\.int).)*$\""```

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried `jest --watch` for TDD? It runs only files related to your git changes, runs errors first and heavily utilise cache for speed.

Other than that, `jest -c` [accepts a path](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#config-path), not a string. You should be good with `jest -c jest-integration-config.json`, provided that *jest-integration-config.json* sits in your project's root.